# Replacing toilet supply line and valve

Tags: toilet, valve

I'm trying to replace the supply line and valve for my toilet but am having a hard time removing the coupling nut. I tried grabbing the fill valve and using a plier to remove the coupling nut but the nut kept moving along with the fill valve.

When I went to buy the supplies, I was told that these don't need to be changed unlike what my plumber told me. When I tried to put everything back, the coupling nut part wouldn't stop leaking. At this point, I think it's better if I just replace it. Any suggestion on how I could remove the coupling nut? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the nut kept moving along with the fill valve.

Have a helper use your pliers to grab on to the fill valve *inside of the tank*; you need to prevent the fill valve from turning. Then remove the supply flex nut by unscrewing with a large adjustable wrench, an open-end wrench, or with your other pliers.

I would go ahead and change everything: stop valve, supply flex, and toilet fill valve.

Answer (score 0):

> grabbing the fill valve and using a plier to remove the coupling nut
>   but the nut kept moving along with the fill valve.

Put away the pliers.

Find TWO wrenches. NOT pliers. Not "pipe wrenches" - these are machined flat surfaces, a common adjustable wrench is what you want, unless you happen to have a non-adjustable wrench that fits the flats correctly.

Hold the nut still with one wrench, while unscrewing the valve with the other wrench. When installing the new valve, also hold the nut still with one wrench while installing the new valve with the other wrench.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried removing the valve yet because I'm still stuck at the coupling nut at the top. A picture of the tools is added. Do these not work?

Answer (score 0):

Shut of the water main .Flush toilet so no more water is in lines. Take a hack saw blade or sawzoll cut of supply, near toilet.  Remove toilet parts with water pump pliers , or what you have. Install new parts to toilet tank. Heat up shut off with hair dryer to loosen seal, Hold on to pipe or where shut off screws into. And wrench off shut off add new one. Be careful not to break pipe at shut off add more heat if needed.

Comment: Your  tools should be fine and work. A wrench that fits ,Nut is better do not snap water line. Add heat if needed .